# React Native Maps (Mapview Marker) not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

**Following is my code segment. Please refer to MapView.Marker, even on giving the coordinates for my current location nothing is displayed, same behavior is observed when i map service locations array and provide latitude,longitude values using it.**

When i use mapview marker like this , a single marker is displayed but as for this component i have to display multiple markers on the map with different coordinates i have to go with Mapview.Marker. Please point out what am i missing here.

```
    export default class index extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          text: "",
          source: require("../../Image/User_default.png"),
          location: {
            latitude: 0,
            latitudeDelta: 0,
            longitude: 0,
            longitudeDelta: 0,
          },
          serviceLocations: [],
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this._getLocationAsync();
        this._getServices();
      }

      _getServices = () => {
        create_service
          .getAllServices()
          .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
              serviceLocations: res,
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      };

      _getLocationAsync = async () => {
        let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
        if (status !== "granted") {
          Alert.alert("Error", "Permission to access location was denied", [
            { text: "OK" },
          ]);
        } else {
          let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
          location_service
            .setCurrentUserLocation(location)
            .then(async (res) => {
              // console.log("_getLocationAsync:", res);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        }
      };

      render() {
        const { serviceLocations } = this.state;
        return (
          <View style={style.container}>
            <MapView
              style={style.mapStyle}
              provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
              region={{
                latitude: 33.650073,
                longitude: 73.153164,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0921,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
              }}
              showsUserLocation={true}
            />
            <Marker/>
            {serviceLocations.length
              ? serviceLocations.map((serviceLocation,key) => {                 
                  return (
                    <MapView.Marker
                      coordinate={{
                        latitude: 33.650073,
                        longitude: 73.153164,
                      }}
                      key={key}
                      // image={require("../../Image/location-pin.png")}
                    />
                  );
                })
              : null}
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorted the solution myself. Actually what i was doing wrong in this code was that i was using the `<Marker>` outside the scope of `<MapView>` which is why markers were not displayed on my maps. 
As soon as i corrected the scope issue my problem was solved.